# Const char to string with string.at()

Tags: c++, string, char, substring, constants

I have a string

```
const std::string myString = "my string";
```

that never changes.

Also, I have the following function:

```
void myFunction(const std::string str);
```

I want to go through the string char by char and do something with each substring (I pass each substring to `myFunction`).

This is the code I came up with first:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < myString.length(); ++i) {
  myFunction(myString.at(i));
}
```

but it gave me the error "cannot convert const char to string". So I came up with the following code:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < myString.length(); ++i) {
  char currentChar[2] = {myString.at(i), '\0'};
  myFunction(currentChar);
}
```

which works but I don't feel good about it.

Is this solution correct? Or is it just coincidence that it works (like undefined behavior but I'm lucky that it works when I test it)?

Also, should the passed string in `myFunction` be const?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to pass to `myFunction`. At the start of the question you say you want to pass a string, and then `myFunction` will go through the string char by char.  But in the rest of the question you attempt to pass a single character to `myFunction`.

Comment: You are walking over the string char by char; what substring are you looking to be passing to `myFunction`?

Comment: Clarified it, sorry about that!

Comment: @A. D.  So, you are treating each character as a sub-string of one character?  If so, why are you passing it as a string instead of a character?

Comment: Why don't you make `myFunction` take a `char` (`void myFunction(char)`)?

Comment: There is no need for the overhead of `myString.at(i)` in that simple loop. Use `myString[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.  It is neither efficient nor beautiful, but it works.

`myFunction` takes a string. You cannot pass it a character. A character and a one-character string are different things.  Further, there is no constructor which transforms character to string.

Since `myFunction` requires a string, you should give it a string, or at least `const char*` which can be implicitly converted to a string.

Are you sure that `myFunction` really needs a string, rather than a character?

On a side note, are you sure that `myFunction` should not receive string *by reference*?

Comment: If you really want to create a string from a character, use `std::string(1, myString.at(i))`.  This constructor says to create a std::string that consists of one copy of the given character.

Comment: @md5i Actually, the best way is to create a 1-character string outside the loop, and change its first character each time.  This way, the constructor is called only once.

Comment: Given that the string is being passed by value, seems a micro-optimization at best.  Most important is to teach the user to create a string when passing a string rather than constructing a char array.  Using `std::string::substr` is also a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @md5i I addressed the issue of passing by value in my answer.  Calling the constructor is expensive.  Note that even passing by value takes time comparable to calling a constructor. So no, it is not a "micro-optimization".  Teaching the user to write efficient code is important, there is too much sloware around.

Comment: Making the function accept `char` is better than passing a 1-character string

Comment: @M.M Thats for sure, and I addressed this issue in my post. But maybe it is called somewhere else with more than 1 character.

Comment: user31264 Correct! I also use it for strings with > 1 char. I now use md5i's answer with your proposed optimization. Thanks!